# Getting relational data with Angular cli front-end stuck

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api2

Back-end and Typescript is working fine since in browser Network tab I get what I want, my problem is that I am stuck in html... I don't know how to display the data.

Here is what I what I get into the console from my web api 2:

```
{
 "Id":1,
 "Name":"testete",
 "Description":"Test",
 "DueDate":"2017-1205T15:14:27.307",
 "IsCompleted":true,
 "Worker":
 [ 
  {
    "Id":1,
    "FirstName":"Johnny",
    "LastName":"Doe",
    "Job":[]
  },
  {"Id":2,"FirstName":"yyyy","LastName":"yyyyy","Job":[]},
  {"Id":3,"FirstName":"bbbbb","LastName":"vvvvvvvv","Job":[]
  }
 ]
```

}

This is my model in case is not right:

```
export class Jobs {
Id: number;
Name: string;
Description: string;
DueDate: Date;
IsCompleted?: boolean;

worker: Worker[];
```

}

This is my attempt in html component to display the data:

```
<label class="labelInputs">Workers Assigned to this job</label>
<div *ngFor="let job of jobs">
    <div *ngFor="let worker of job.worker">
        <label class="labelInputs" value="worker">
            {{worker.FirstName}}
        </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

I get this error: `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

It might be misleading because I don't even know how to display something nested so if someone can show me I would appreciate very much.

I just want to display the workers first name in labels that are present in "Worker" thats all.

Thank you very much

EDIT:
This is how I get my jobs.

```
getJobs(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.jobsService.getJob(id)
        .subscribe(jobs => this.jobs = jobs);
}
```

This is my service:

```
getJob(id: number): Observable<Jobs> {
    const url = `${this.apiURL}/${id}`;

    return this.http.get<Jobs>(url);
}
```

Here initialization of Jobs and Workers as arrays or objects:

```
@Input() jobs: Jobs;

public Job: Jobs;
public Jobs: Jobs[];

public workers: Worker[];
public worker: Worker;
```

Comment: Where `jobs = Array<Jobs>()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to exlude your first `*ngFor` loop as you can't iterate an Object.

```
<label class="labelInputs">Workers Assigned to this job</label>
<div *ngFor="let worker of Jobs.worker">
    <label class="labelInputs" value="worker">
         {{worker.FirstName}}
    </label>
</div>
```

---

You also need to populate Jobs and Workers.

So...

```
export class Jobs {
...
  constructor(){
   this.Workers = new Array<Worker>();
  }
}
```

Then you need to add the data which you received from the server through something like:

```
job = new Jobs();
for each(var worker in data.Worker){
   Job.Workers.push(worker as Worker);
}
```

**Update:**

Here is a working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mgDWeyXKkaRRLDQuz2Ge?p=preview) which demonstrates this better.

Comment: I feel like you are right but I am so bad with Angular. So I defined this `Jobs: Jobs[];` or like this `jobs = Array<Jobs>()` in my ts component and in this `Jobs.worker` is saying "worker is not defined". If I am doing like this` Job: Jobs;` my intellsense is seeing the worker but here: `{{worker.FirstName}}` I get "FirstName is not defined"

Comment: Please see my update @Eduard. You need to instantiate Jobs correctly - not just the Array. :)

Comment: Ok its getting confusing. First of all "a constructor cannot have a this parameter" it works in ngOnInit. But then where goes the for each? To get my jobs I used the method in the question I edited right now. There I should use my foreach?

Comment: @Eduard please see the working plunkr for an example.

Comment: Thank you, its working with `private data: any = { ... }` but how I can change `this.data` so I get the data from server. Because that data is there in console when I load the page. I can't do it like this `this.getJobs()`. I feel so bad being awful at this, like it was fairly easy everything else. I will just mark it as answer because its correct even if I am bad at it.

Comment: @Eduard I would do: `private data: any;` and then in the constructor... `this.data = (call to your server to get the data like you had before)`. Glad I could help.